# Stacked area chart display eventhough df contains 0 or NaN

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using df.plot.area() and am very confused by the result. The dataframe has integers as index. The values to plot are in different columns. One column contains zeros from a specific integer onwards, however I can still see a thin line in the plot which isn't right.

After data processing this is the code I am using to actually plot:

```
# Start plotting
df.plot(kind='area', stacked=True, color=colors)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(mylabel, fontsize=12)

# Reverse Legend
ax = plt.gca()
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1])

plt.title(filename[:-4])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
```

And this is a [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WkUN.png) of the result, the orange thin line shouldn't be visiable because the value in the dataframe is zero.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: You seem to be using a pretty thick linewidth. Set it to 0 to get rid of it.

Comment: How obvious! Of course! Thanks, this worked!